# How does this %2F attack work in IIS?

Tags: iis

I'm reading this presentation https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aeNq_5wVwHRR1np1jIRQM1hocrgcZ6Qu/view?pli=1

And I couldn't understand page 48,

[image]

The author didn't say much about it, does anyone know how it works?